# Add a remote computer into my network neighborhood by ip address?

Tags: networking, remote

Some years ago, I was working with a contractor who needed me to access a few things on his computer.  I dimly remember that he had me add his ip address into a file that was buried about 4 directories deep in the windows directory (I think this was windows 2000 on both ends), and magically his computer then showed up in my network neighborhood exactly as if it were in our local lan.

For the life of me, I don't remember what file that was, but I remember clearly that simply adding an ip to it was all that was necessary.

Anyone know what that was?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`lmhosts`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LMHOSTS), somewhere under the Windows `system32\` directory.

Comment: The hosts file would be a more likely and common candidate.

Comment: Except that `hosts` is not used for that.